# How to serialize a large JSON object directly to HttpResponseMessage stream?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, httpclient

Is there any way to stream a large JSON object directly to the HttpResponseMessage stream?

Here is my existing code:

```
        Dictionary<string,string> hugeObject = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        // fill with 100,000 key/values.  Each string is 32 chars.
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(
            content: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hugeObject),
            encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
            mediaType: "application/json");
```

Which works fine for smaller objects.  However, the process of calling JsonConvert.SerializeObject() to convert the object into a string is causing problematic memory spikes for large objects.

I want to do the equivalent of [what's described here for deserialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/performance.htm).

Comment: Could you post the structure of your large object?

Comment: Added example of hugeObject...

Comment: Did you try the [Manual Serialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/performance.htm#ID3RBSection) section on that page you linked?

Comment: @krillgar that seems promising but I'm not sure what to write to.  I can create a StreamContent HttpContent for the response but I have to provide the stream.

Comment: Using Separation of Concerns, I would create a class, like `JsonConvert` to handle the conversion process. You *should* add a method to each of your objects, if you have them available to write that object to the stream. If you're working on something like `Dictionary<string, string>`, then you obviously don't have that ability, and can keep it encapsulated within the new class.

Comment: With `Dictionary<string,string>` you don't necessarily need a serializer. Why don't you just go through every _entry_ of the dictionary and build your json by writing `"Key": "Value"` to a `Stringbuilder`?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a [`PushStreamContent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.pushstreamcontent(v=vs.118).aspx) and write to it with a [`JsonTextWriter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter.htm):

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new PushStreamContent((stream, content, context) =>
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    using (JsonTextWriter jtw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
    {
        JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
        ser.Serialize(jtw, hugeObject);
    }
}, "application/json");
```